# How to move to MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I made WPF application using Devexpress and Ado.net Connectivity mode with data base.I worked in other languages and now move to C#, i am new to WPF .I wrote this code to edit single and grouped rows:

```
void EditRow(int focRowHand, nrcsaEntities a)
        {

        Name nametext = grid.GetRow(focRowHand) as Name;      
        try
            {
            if (nametext.Name1 != string.Empty)
                {

                update_id = nametext.PK_ID;
                txtName2.Text = update_text = nametext.Name1;

                if (Panel3.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                    {
                    Panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    Panel3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }

                else
                    {
                    Panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    Panel3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (Exception err)
            {
            DXMessageBox.Show(err.StackTrace);

            }

        }

    private void ToggleButton1_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        if (view.FocusedRowHandle == -1)
            {
            DXMessageBox.Show("Please Select any Item From Grid List");
            }
        else
            {
            try
                {
                int FocRowHand = view.FocusedRowHandle;
                nrcsaEntities a = new nrcsaEntities();

                if (grid.IsGroupRowHandle(FocRowHand))
                    {
                    int childCount = grid.GetChildRowCount(FocRowHand);
                    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
                        {
                        int childHandle = grid.GetChildRowHandle(FocRowHand, i);
                        EditRow(childHandle, a);
                        }
                    }
                else
                    {
                    EditRow(FocRowHand, a);

                    }

                }
            catch (Exception ee)
                {
                DXMessageBox.Show(ee.StackTrace);
                }
            }
```

As my client demands to generate code with high quality. It is possible that more than 1000 users will use this application and can save users data more than 5000, My Question is that : As i have less time to submit my application to my client.  If i want to convert this code into MVVM, how to do this as it's little complex to convert for me. Secondly, What do you think about this code quality. I am very much confuse about this. I am looking forward to your reply.

Comment: This might be more appropraite on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you are on a tight deadline, forget converting it to MVVM. Your code is to tightly connected to your Views. You put your code in CodeBehind, which is an absolute no-go for MVVM. For MVVM you need ViewModels which contain **NO UI SPECIFIC CODE AT ALL** and all of your other stuff in Model. Views in MVVM consist of only XAML Code + Auto-generated CodeBehind (in best case). In MVVM you use CodeBehind only for UI specific code (i.e. if you want validation to trigger while user types into the textbox) but no Logic

Comment: MVVM ist something you have to consider **BEFORE** starting to develop your application. If your code is not designed for it, it requires huge amount of refactoring or starting from scratch.

Comment: @Tseng thank you for suggestion, what do u think about it's quality / Worry about quality/ :(

Comment: @ZoyaSheikh `what do u think about it's quality` - Your code is horrible. Anyone who is used to MVVM sees non-MVVM as childish, spaghetti, unnecesary code written by someone who is not a mature, experienced programmer, but rather all the opposite. If your client is demanding `high quality` code, you'd rather not submit this.

Comment: @HighCore yes...i was thinking it too.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take more days from your client and go for [Devexpress MVVM Scaffolding Wizard](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/theonewith/archive/2013/06/13/new-wpf-mvvm-scaffolding-wizard-released-in-v2013-1.aspx) It is ready to use. You have to just make connection to database and just have to change interface of your application.

Answer (score 4):

All I can tell you is that if you convert this application to WPF and MVVM in particular, then you will need to re-write a LOT of code. One problem is that WPF is *very* different from other languages... most developers face an uphill struggle when first learning WPF because of these differences.

Then, if you want to use the MVVM design pattern, things become even more different... for example, it is generally frowned upon to write code in code behind files. Of course, it *is* possible to use the code behind files, but we tend to implement `Attached Properties` that 'wrap' the functionality of these UI control event handlers, such as `SelectionChanged` instead.

Typically, the code that you have shown us would have to be moved into a view model, but then you'd lose the ability to reference your controls and so you'd have to find other ways to re-implement the same behaviour, but in an MVVM way. You'd also need to implement a load of `ICommand` instances to replace a lot of your `Click` handlers, etc.

Now, I must admit that my comments so far *may* make you think that I am *not* recommending that you convert your project. However, I am *not* not recommending that you convert your project. There *are* great benefits to WPF and using the MVVM pattern... the graphics, animations, styles and the ability to make any control look like anything else among other things.

The last point that I'd like to make relates to your question about 'big data'. WPF *is* a processor hungry framework... there's no way around this. It *can* be slow when rendering tens of thousands of data items into pretty UI elements. However, after working on a large scale application for a couple of years now, I've found that there *are* ways of improving the situation.

We can make WPF use the power of installed graphics cards, or use virtualised panels that only load data for the visible items, among other things. You really need to hear this negative side of WPF before you start your conversion, because once it has been converted, it'll be too late. I would also recommend that the computers that will run the application are made powerful enough, one way or another.

I hope this 'summary' has not been too negative for you and has helped in some way. I would like to end by saying that I personally am a *huge* fan of both WPF and MVVM.

Comment: I have to agree with Sheridan. WPF/MVVM is great, but porting to it is not a job to tackle when under a deadline. Instead go and write a couple of simple applications as WPF/MVVM so you understand it first.

Comment: I agree with Sheridan

Comment: I find it at least curious that you're making an extensive answer about MVVM without mentioning the word `DataBinding`, not even once. Still, +1.

Comment: @HighCore, feel free to add a section.